# Compile python grpc proto with a gitlab commit

Tags: python, gitlab, gitlab-ci, grpc-python

I have some gRPC proto definitions that I'd like to compile to python generated code and commit to my gitlab repo each time there's any commit made to the repo.

I suspect I need to implement some sort of CI/CD pipeline but I haven't managed to find out how to do what I need.

Is it a simple case of implementing below as a pipleline and will it commit the generated code to the repo without any further interaction?

```
stages:
  - build

build-job:
  stage: build
  script:
    - python3 -m grpc_tools.protoc -I . --python_out=. --grpc_python_out=. MyService.proto
```

I could test it, but I'd rather have a better idea of what it will do before I start playing around.

Any help would be appreciated,

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

It would be better if you could explain more about the problem you are trying to solve.

1. Firstly you don't need to compile protos everytime (Unless the actual proto definition is modified)
2. Yes, You need a CI/CD pipeline to automate compile protos and commit them.

> Watch out for the trigger though, as Just `push to main` trigger in this case would cause an infinite loop.
> The better trigger would be `push to main + change in proto file`

Hope this helps.